# Pdf generation using component one library in Arabic language

Tags: pdf, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, componentone

I have generated pdf in a required format in english but when I switch my ui to arabic language and generate pdf it generates mirrored image in pdf.

I have used [this tutorial](http://our.componentone.com/2014/04/22/export-your-ui-to-pdf/) to generate pdf. Anyone know why it is not working in arabic language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up checking for language and then flipping my image like this.

```
if (!App.IsEnglishSelected)
    {
        wb = wb.Flip(WriteableBitmapExtensions.FlipMode.Vertical);
    }
```